# Prove something about power-series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

Lets say that for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$$,a_n\ne0$.

If, $$\lim_{n\to 0}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=l$$ how do I prove that the radius of the convergence of the series:$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$$ 
is $\frac{1}{|l|}$ if $l\ne 0$ and $\infty$ is $l=0$.

I have no idea how to prove it...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : Apply ratio test to $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n x^n$$ .

EDIT : No problem if $n=0$ or $n=1$ as finite terms doesn't affect the convergence.

Comment: It's matter if it's from $n=0$ and not $n=1$?

Comment: @YoavFridman: convergence of series only depends on the tail of the series, not on the beginning.

Comment: I don't know if $l>1$ or $l<1$...

Comment: You must determine which $x$'s which make the ratio less than $1$ , and hence have your radius of convergence

Answer (score 1):

Let $R=\frac {1}{|l|}$.For example if $$|x|<R=>|a_nx^n|=|a_n||x|^n=|a_n|R^n\frac {|x|^n}{R^n}\leq M (\frac {|x|}{R})^n$$ and $\sum (\frac {|x|}{R})^n$ is a geometric series.

Try the rest.